# How should I send params to a Asp.Net WebAPI 2.1 data query method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have been coding like this. Sometimes there are one, two, three or more parameters:

```
$http({ url: '/api/Topic/Retrieve',
    method: "GET",
    params: {
       subjectId: sub
    }
})
```

The result is like this with all the query params as part of the query string:

```
GET /api/Topic/Retrieve?subjectId=1 HTTP/1.1
```

My WebAPI controllers look like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Retrieve(int subjectId)
    {
        var topics = await db.Topics
            .Include(q => q.SubTopics)
            .Where(q => q.SubjectId == subjectId)
            .ToListAsync();
        return Ok(topics);
    }
```

This works but now I am setting up Asp.Net attribute route decorations and there is no simple way to do that when I use the query string to pass data. So **should I** do something like the following if there are one, two or three parameters?

```
GET /api/Topic/1 HTTP/1.1
GET /api/Topic/1/2 HTTP/1.1
GET /api/Topic/1/2/abcd HTTP/1.1
```

Or **alternatively** should I code the parameters `in the body` and then use: `[FromBody]` before the parameters to the Asp.Net method ? One more question. If I code the parameters in the body then how would I do that with AngularJS. Should I use the `data` param in the $http call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define the method access name for your `Retrieve` method by

`[HttpGet("Retrieve")]`

and continue using query parameters like you were originally without messing with the route.

(Similar to this answer: [Web API 2 / MVC 5 : Attribute Routing passing parameters as querystring to target different actions on same controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391066/web-api-2-mvc-5-attribute-routing-passing-parameters-as-querystring-to-targe))